# How to implement a monitor between mongodb and elasticsearch in ELK itself. So, if there would be lag it triggers an alert

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, monitoring, kibana-7

I am trying to implement a monitoring between Mongodb and elasticsearch itself in ELK. However, I am clueless where to begin.
Whether is it possible without installing any third party plugin?
Would really appreciate if someone from community could guide me.

I tried to collect mongodb metric and elastic search but somehow stuck at how to find desync between both and how to implement this monitoring in ELk.